# Passing correct value to moment.js `toDate() function`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

In my timepicker component in my react-native app I need to pass a value into moment's `toDate()` function, because that's the format the component requires.

The value I have is a clock value, coming in as a string, such as "14:23".

My question is, how can I take that clock string value, attach it to a date, and then format it in such a way that I can pass that all in as the value for `val` to be passed in here:

```
 this.value = moment(val).toDate();
```

I tried this:

```
const val = "14:24"

const m = moment(`2022-02-19:${val}`);
console.log('isValid: ', m.isValid()); // false
```

But this fails.

But, for that matter, so does this:

```
const m = moment("2011-10-10T10:20:90");
console.log('isValid: ', m.isValid()); // false
```

So I guess that's not surprising, and suggests there's something I'm not understanding here. Bottom line how can I format a value, with a string value like "14:24", and then pass it to moment's `toDate()` function?

```
  this.value = moment(val).toDate();
```

Comment: [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parses the input string as moment object as long as the input is in ISO 8601/RFC 2822 compliant format, [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parses your input string according the formatting tokens you pass as second argument, while [`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)  simply returns _a copy of the native Date object that Moment.js wraps_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment has a formatter that formats then parses this string into a JavaScript date. The current format you're using is not the standard ISO8601 format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ, so moment will not natively support it, because you're using a : symbol after the day, not the letter "T".

You can easily get the desired effect by changing your code like so:

```js
const m = moment(`2022-02-19T${val}`);
```

Alternatively, you can change moments defaultFormatter to support whatever format you want. To do this, you can simply call it like this:

```js
moment.defaultFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm"
```

Or simply explicitly pass the formatter into moment alongside the datestring like this:

```js
const m = moment(`2022-02-19:${val}`, "YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm").toDate()
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but JS natively renders all dates in local time unless told otherwise, so this dateobject will be in the users local timezone. Or are you asking how to get the date to represent that time today? If so you just generate a new js object and read the year, month and day with moment, I can give you an example of that if that's what you're trying to achieve.